# Proper port forwarding

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, port-forwarding

I try to do port forwarding correctly (under Ubuntu and use [Transmission](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo) in active mode). **Could this be my provider?**

I opened port in my Technicolor 7200 router using [this guide](https://portforward.com/technicolor/tc7200/) as follows:

[image]

Then, I opened a port via terminal:

```
sudo ufw allow 6881
```

**sudo ufw status numbered** gives:

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 6881                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 6881 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

**netstat -lntu** outputs:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6881            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
...................................     
tcp6       0      0 :::6881                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

But, when I check if port is open using [this](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) service, it says:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

While it looks like you have exposed the port to the world, the port will show as closed unless there is a service listening on that port. I suspect that when you did the test your torrent client was either not running or was not interested in communicating with the test website.

Comment: I run Transmission with the port specified, but the result is the same. Transmisison also says the port is closed. **netstat -lntu** gives **0.0.0.0:6881            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN**

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that those ports are actually open on your Linux client:

```
netstat -lntu
```

This will output open ports on your Linux machine. 
Make sure that the ports that you want open are listed and are set to listen. Even if your router forwards those ports correctly, your Linux machine needs to accept that traffic.

Your ISP has assigned you a dynamic IP address which means it can be subject to change, but this will only cause an issue if / when that IP address actually changes. If you want a Static IP address, one that won't change, check with your ISP if they offer them.

Comment: I tried that command and the only ports with LISTEN have 127.0.0.1 as the local address. Also, ISPs can offer static IPs only for extra money. I wonder how people use torrents??

Comment: Have you ensured that you have set up a local static IP for your Linux machine like the guide you have posted shows?

Comment: Yes, I did. Via **etc/network/interfaces**